# Compiler optimizations for equality checked stores

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, compiler-optimization

Consider this code snippet:

```
static std::atomic<bool> var; //the variable to update.

// Update() updates the variable `var`
void Update() {
     bool result = Foo(); //Foo() is some function returning a boolean.

     // The doubt is here in this conditional store.
     var.compare_exchange_strong(!result, result);
}
```

If Update() is called frequently, say multiple threads, one wouldn't want to store `result` to `var` if already `var == result` due to cache failures.

The question follows:

1. Does `if (result != var) var = result` get optimized to `var = result` ?
2. Does this optimization (if any) differ if var is not an atomic?

Edit: I am talking in purview of gcc. Comments about icc/clang are welcome.

Edit: So after replacing the if with `var.compare_exchange_strong(!result, result);` now the store will only happen if the existing value is !result. Am I correct?

Comment: Which compiler are you asking about? Not all compilers optimize the same. (And sometimes those optimizations are proprietary.)

Comment: *Does if (result != var) var = result get optimized to var = result ?* This makes no sense. There is no such code in the example. Please edit the question accordingly.